How to create an Android Intent to the AMAP application with multiple waypoints?
How to create an Android Intent to open the AMAP application with multiple waypoints?
I tried this URI
// Create the URI for the Intent
String uri = "amapuri://route/plan/?dlat=destination_lat&dlon=destination_lng&dname=Destination&waypoints=" + waypoints;

But only gets the first and the last location when the AMAP application opens, I could not find in the AMAP documentation how to add in the URI waypoints.
This specific attribute waypoints that I added, I did not found in the official documentation.
https://developer.amap.com/api/amap-mobile/guide/android/navigation

See the AMAP URI API documentation ...
The property is being called via, that's why the unknown property waypoints is being ignored.
Waypoints are only available in driving mode.

Your sugestion was good, but instead opening directly the app, it opened a web browser. So I needed to create a WebView in my application to then create an automatic click in the button in the WebView, and then this would open the amap application with multiple waypoints.
